# Good practices with azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to know if there is some good practices in azure logic apps to make the logic app more performatic.. For example instead of using loops to filter arrays or compose new arrays of objects i can use the filter and select actions to increase the performance of the logic app.

What i want to know is if there is other ways to increase the performance without using azure functions or something like that just with actions that azure logic apps has.

Comment: Hi, if still have any conern about your question, please let me know.

Comment: Any update for this post ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use azure function in your logic app, you can add "[Execute JavaScript Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code)" action in your logic app instead of using azure function.

Before using "**Execute JavaScript Code**" action, you need to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account?tabs=azure-portal) an integration account and link it to your logic app. Then you can write code in "**Execute JavaScript Code**" action.

For other requirements to replace the functionality of your azure function, you can find if there is a match connector/actions in this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list).